# Username field removal at login in DJANGO(REST)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I recently wanted to remove the username field, which is required for registration, in my Django REST API. So I added the following lines in my `settings.py`:

```
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
```

Username is no longer required at registration. But when a user tries to login it still requires a username otherwise I will get a `{'non_field_errors': ['Unable to log in with provided credentials.']}` as response. I also noticed that when a user registers with a email address only, django takes all the characters before the @ sign in the email address, and saves that as username in the database.

> My question is:
>
> How can I also remove the username at login. So the only thing needed
>   to login is the email and password. I am trying to achieve this
>   without making custom user models.

**A example of the current situation at registration and login, respectively:**

```
#Registration
registartion_info ={"email":"achie@gmail.com", "password1":"password","password2":"password"}
registration_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/registration/'
response = requests.post(url,json= registartion_info)

#Login
login_info ={"username":"achie","email":"achie@gmail.com", "password":"password"}
login_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/login/'
response = requests.post(url,json= login_info)
```

**A example of how I want the registration and login to be, respectively:**

```
#Registration
registartion_info ={"email":"achie@gmail.com", "password1":"password","password1":"password"}
registration_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/registration/'
response = requests.post(url,json= registartion_info)

#Login
login_info ={"email":"achie@gmail.com", "password":"password"}
login_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/login/'
response = requests.post(url,json= login_info)
```

Comment: So, how does a user login?

Comment: Please check the question again I updated it with a example.

Comment: A quick workaround would be to just set username as the email id or you'll have to create an authentication backend which authenticates with email and pass

Comment: Also, the user model is an inbuilt mechanism of Django... the whole ecosystem is build upon it. Without creating your own custom model, I don't see a way to remove the username field entirely.

Comment: Do you a have any suggestions of setting the username as email id when a post is send request send. How would you do this?